# Javascript plotly how to reduce amount of rendered points to amount of pixels

Tags: plotly.js

I'm rendering huge amounts of data points 200.000+ in plotly.js. Most graphs are 2d (also 3d, but first focus on 2d). I also render multiple of these graphs next to each other in widgets. As you will know the performance gets quite ugly with these amounts of rendered points.

All points are sorted. X-Axis is time, so basically it's easy to filter close points just iterating and comparing current to previous value.

Is there a way to inject a filter function that would compare current data-point (to be rendered) to previous data-point (rendered or collected for rendering) and if current data-point lands on same pixel as previous, skip the current data-point ? or if delta is less than some margin-x (dependent on zoom level) skip point ?

or any equivalent ideas ?

of course if I have a line-type graph it could even make sense to reduce a group of values that would all land on the same x-value (in pixels) with diverse y values to just be reduced to the y-min and the y-max value of that group, so instead of having a vertical line with 20 dots I would just have the min and max.

But that function would of course need to be reevaluated on each zoom or resize.

I found filter and aggregate transforms, but I'm not sure yet if they could be used somehow to fit the mentioned needs.

If there's no integrated functionality I'll have to bind to some thrown events but I guess that will be less performant than a possible built in hook.